# Overriding Equals() breaking comparison with null?

Tags: unity-game-engine, equals

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, especially since I'm reimplementing something i've had working fine before, specifically AStar algorithm for pathfinding. I'm using C# and working in Unity in case that matters. Main difference between my previous implementation and the current one is that I previously had Navigation Nodes as seperate game objects in Unity and now they're just class instances in a 3d array. First unexpected obstacle i've had was i had to override Equals() method this time around just so List<>.Contains() would properly respond to different nodes being checked (was not necessary before). Override helped, but later I found myself stuck on a pretty odd issue (at least for me at this point). Here's a piece of code that's causing me issues now:

```
public static List<Vector3> PrintPath (ref NavNode node, ref NavNode caller)
    {
            caller.parent = null;
            List<Vector3> temp = new List<Vector3> ();
            NavNode tempNode = node;
            Debug.Log(tempNode.parent.parent.parent.position);
            while (tempNode.parent!=null) {
                    temp.Add (tempNode.position);
                    Debug.Log (tempNode.position);
                    tempNode = tempNode.parent;
            }
            temp.Add (tempNode.position);
            temp.Reverse();
            return temp;
    }
```

Thing here is that I'm certain tempNode.parent is not null, that Debug statement works fine in console, i can go even deeper referencing further parents. My code never goes into that while() loop however (once again - this is something i've had working before in earlier implementation). Also, the loop starts executing if i switch from "tempNode.parent!=null" to "tempNode.parent==null", in that scenario it goes through all steps fine, throwing null reference on that last parent in the hierarchy.
Here's the Override for Equals() i've used:

```
    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    NavNode node = (NavNode)obj;
    if ((System.Object)node == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (node.position.x == position.x) && (node.position.y == position.y) && (node.position.z == position.z);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Anyone got any idea what I might be doing wrong? Spent several hours trying to figure this out, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this one out on my own after all. If anyone encounters similar issue, here's an explanation: Indeed the fact that I've had the nodes as seperate game object components in the first implementation and that in the second one they were just instances in an array has made the difference. Apparently each time a scripts extends Monobehavior it needs to be used as a game object component in order to function properly. Once i've removed the Monobehavior extension from my new NavNode class I no longer had to override the Equals() method, the default one started working properly. In consequence, also the null check that was causing me problems started to work correctly as well.